# elasticsearch 5.0 and index template

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm moving from elasticsearch 2.x to elasticsearch 5.0.  During startup elasticsearch tells me I can no longer define index properties in the elasticsearch.yml . Through the elasticsearch 5.0 documentation I found out I needed to use index templates to set default parameters that were set in the elasticsearch.yml in version 2.x.  In my case I had the following setup

```
index:
  number_of_shards: 1
  number_of_replicas: 1
  similarity:
    default:
      type: BM25
      b:0.0
      k1:1.2
    norm_bm25:
      type: BM25
      b:0.75
      k1:1.2
```

Using and index template instead, I tried to convert this to

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_template/template1' -d '{
  "template" : "*",  
  "settings.index.number_of_replicas" : "1",
  "settings.index.number_of_shards" : "1",
  "settings.index.similarity.default.b" : "0.0",
  "settings.index.similarity.default.k1" : "1.2",
  "settings.index.similarity.default.type" : "BM25",
  "settings.index.similarity.norm_bm25.b" : "0.75",
  "settings.index.similarity.norm_bm25.k1" : "1.2",
  "settings.index.similarity.norm_bm25.type" : "BM25"
}'
```

I'm using elasticsearch.js version 12. and getting the error

```
Error: [illegal_argument_exception] unknown setting [index.similarity]
```

which I assume is because I am setting the similarity in the wrong way in the template.  My javascript code remains unchanged from the upgrade to elasticsearch 5.0, however, the offending javascript code, resulting in the error is

```
client.indices.create({
  index: indexName,
  body: { settings: { 
          number_of_shards: 1,
          similarity : "norm_bm25"
  } 
},....error stuff)
```

What is the correct way to correctly convert my elasticsearch.yml to a set of curl operation so that it works in elasticsearch 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write template is

```
PUT _template/template1
{
  "template": "*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "index": {
      "similarity": {
        "default": {
          "type": "BM25",
          "b": 0,
          "k": 1.2
        },
        "norm_bm25": {
          "type": "BM25",
          "b": 0.75,
          "k": 1.2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can refer to [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#default-base) for more info. You would copy the same settings dictionary in your javascript code.